# Is there any solution for this error: invalid type key

Tags: recaptcha

I have integrated **Google Recaptcha** on my WordPress contact form pages, but I am getting an error message that I am not understanding. I have tried lot of proposed solution in vain. Here is the error nature:

> **ERREUR pour le propriétaire du site : Type de clé non valide**

I reset and changed the key several times.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rXKM.png)

Answer (score 2):

i finally got a way out to solve my problem. in fact the problem was about the captcha version, i was trying to integrate the Version 3, that was not working, then i downgrade to version 2 and it is working perfectly for my case.